# asp.net progress loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, loading

I have a page that is taking a couple of seconds to load due to a lot of data being displayed.

How can i make it so that it plays a .gif animation until the data is ready to be displayed in a table instead of not having anything displayed?

How to set the table/content to display only after the loading is complete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use asp.net ajax control, for example ScriptManager + UpdateProgress + UpdatePanel.
    Here an example

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" id="PageUpdateProgress">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Loading...
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="Panel">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" id="UpdateButton" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Update" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>


protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```